# How to implement .ChildWhere() mapping with many-to-many relation in NH 3.2

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, conform

I have following FNH mapping:

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
   public ItemMap ()
   {
       this.HasManyToMany(a => a.ChildItems).ChildWhere("IsDeleted = 0").AsSet();
   }
}
```

Result hbm file is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Item" table="Item">
    <set name="ChildItems" table="ItemsToChildItems">
      ...
      <many-to-many class="ChildItem" where="IsDeleted = 0">
        <column name="ChildItemId" />
      </many-to-many>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want to implement the same mapping using *"sexy mapping by code feature :-) / conformist approach"* of NHibernate 3.2

**Note:**
Following approach doesn't work:

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMapping<Item>
{
   public ItemMap()
   {
      this.Set(x => x.ChildItems
      , map =>
      {
         map.Where("IsDeleted = 0");
      }
      , action => action.ManyToMany());
   }
}
```

**Because:**
It is following FNH mapping:

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
   public ItemMap ()
   {
      this.HasManyToMany(a => a.ChildItems).Where("IsDeleted = 0").AsSet();
   }
}
```

***.Where("IsDeleted = 0") and .ChildWhere("IsDeleted = 0") not the same.***

**HBM differences:**

Result hbm file using `.ChildWhere("IsDeleted = 0")` is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Item" table="Item">
    <set name="ChildItems" table="ItemsToChildItems">
      ...
      <many-to-many class="ChildItem" where="IsDeleted = 0">
        <column name="ChildItemId" />
      </many-to-many>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Result hbm file using `.Where("IsDeleted = 0")` is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Item" table="Item">
    <set name="ChildItems" table="ItemsToChildItems" where="IsDeleted = 0">
      ...
      <many-to-many class="ChildItem">
        <column name="ChildItemId" />
      </many-to-many>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Who have a similar problem or can offer a solution? Need help.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem and I found a solution:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2997

Solution in 3 steps:

1) Add new interface method to IManyToManyMapper interface:

`public interface IManyToManyMapper : IColumnsMapper
{

   void Where(string sqlWhereClause); 
}`

2) Implement new method in ManyToManyCustomizer class:

`public void Where(string sqlWhereClause)
{ 
  customizersHolder.AddCustomizer(propertyPath, (IManyToManyMapper x) =>    x.Where(sqlWhereClause)); 
}`

3) Implement new method in ManyToManyMapper class:

`public void Where(string sqlWhereClause) 
{ 
   manyToMany.where = sqlWhereClause; 
}`